# How to make a wrapper module that includes functions from other modules?

Tags: macros, elixir, metaprogramming

Working on a web app using the CQRS pattern (via [Commanded](https://github.com/commanded/commanded)), and would like to expose functions from the `Read` and `Write` modules in a single module. For example, to hide the implementation details of a context from Phoenix controllers.

---

<sup>I know, could've just simply divide the context module (e.g., `Accounts`) into two parts.</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer posted before is extremely overcomplicated. We have [`Kernel.defdelegate/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#defdelegate/2) for that exact purpose. Also, it’s still unclear how to handle modules with *equally named functions*.

```rb
defmodule M1, do: def f1, do: 42
defmodule M2, do: def f2(_a1, _a2), do: 42

defmodule Wrapper do
  defmacro __using__(modules) do
    user_defs =
      modules
      |> Enum.map(&Macro.expand(&1, __ENV__))
      |> Enum.map(&{&1, &1.module_info(:exports)})

    for {module, exports} <- user_defs do
      for {func, arity} <- exports, func not in ~w|module_info __info__|a do
        args = for i <- 0..arity, i > 0,
          do: Macro.var(:"arg#{i}", __MODULE__)

        quote do
          # Use as: unquote("#{func}_#{module}") to resolve dups
          defdelegate unquote(func)(unquote_splicing(args)),
            to: unquote(module), as: unquote(func)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Test, do: use Wrapper, [M1,M2]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was fairly sure I was overcomplicating it, and even Jose is mentioning `Kernel.defdelegate/2`. I also did not think of functions with the same name and arity, so kudos again!

Comment: Welcome! I am pretty sure the code above might be tweaked a bit more to avoid the necessity of local `user_defs` but the main point was to mention `Kernel.defdelegate/2`. Also, you might want to check how to avoid having a separate clause for zero when iterating through a range starting with `1` (`args` part.)

Answer (score 0):

The main credit goes to [@velimir for his 5 year-old-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25712951/1498178), but the resources at the end were also invaluable. The differences from @velimir's solution is that passed Elixir modules need to be `Macro.expand/2`-ed (as they are not simple atoms), and that it can handle multiple arguments<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>[1] For some reason, when I used `Enum.each/2` instead of the list comprehension below for the `quote` block, it wouldn't work.</sup>

`Wrapper` iterates through all the exports of
  the  provided modules,  and creates  a function  for
  each, that  calls the function  of the same  name of
  the corresponding module.

For example,  `use Wrapper, [A,B]`, would create
  the following functions (where `A`
  has `lofa/0`  and `B` has `miez/0`):

```
def lofa, do: A.lofa()
def miez, do: B.miez()
```

The `Wrapper` module:

```
defmodule Wrapper do

  defmacro __using__(modules) do

    user_defs =
      Enum.reduce(modules, [], fn(mod_ast, acc) ->
        exports =
          mod_ast
          |> Macro.expand(__ENV__)
          |> apply(:module_info, [:exports])

        pre_defs = [module_info: 0, module_info: 1, __info__: 1]

        [ {mod_ast, exports -- pre_defs} | acc]
      end)

    for {module, exports} <- user_defs do
      for {func_name, arity} <- exports do
        args = make_args(arity)
        quote do
          def unquote(func_name)(unquote_splicing(args)) do
            unquote(module).unquote(func_name)(unquote_splicing(args))
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  defp make_args(0), do: []
  defp make_args(arity) do
    Enum.map 1..arity, &(Macro.var :"arg#{&1}", __MODULE__)
  end
end
```

---

#### Resources

- https://elixirforum.com/t/pass-module-to-a-macro/978
- https://elixirforum.com/t/collect-modules-that-use-some-other-module-at-compile-time/13742
- https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-call-a-function-at-compile-time/619
- https://elixirforum.com/t/what-is-the-return-value-of-quote-block/328/6
- Saša Jurić’s ["Understanding Macros" series](https://www.theerlangelist.com/article/macros_1)
- Chris McCord's [Metaprogramming Elixir](https://pragprog.com/book/cmelixir/metaprogramming-elixir)
- https://andrealeopardi.com/posts/compile-time-work-with-elixir-macros/
- [In Elixir, is there any way to get a module to list its functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664119/in-elixir-is-there-any-way-to-get-a-module-to-list-its-functions)
- [Macro expansion in elixir: how to define 2 macros with one using the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893989/macro-expansion-in-elixir-how-to-define-2-macros-with-one-using-the-other)
- https://dockyard.com/blog/2017/12/07/macro-madness-how-to-use-use-well

Thank you all!

Comment: `Enum.each/2` didn’t work because `__using__/1` is a _macro_ and _macros_ are supposed to return AST to be injected into the place where it was called from. `Enum.flat_map/2` would obviously work. Comprehensions return the list of what the inner `do` block returned (unless `into:` is passed as an argument.)